# DateTimeOffset date doesn't include records with end date

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016, datetimeoffset

I would like to get the database records by a date range including the data with the end date range included. The `TimeStamp` column in the database is a type of `dateTime2(7)`. The date and time is stored in `UTC`. But, I'm displaying the data based on the users time zone. To achieve this, I'm looking up the time zone and then converting it to `BaseUtfOffset` in `C#`. Ex. `3/18/2020` and  `3/29/2020`

```
 var newOffSetDate = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);

 DateTimeOffset d1 = new DateTimeOffset(Convert.ToDateTime(date1), newOffSetDate.BaseUtcOffset);
 DateTimeOffset d2 = new DateTimeOffset(Convert.ToDateTime(date2), newOffSetDate.BaseUtcOffset);
```

I then pass the start and end dates in procedure (type of `DateTimeOffset` parameter) created here to do a simple select statement in SQL. The data returned is only including the records with start date.

```
create table MyTable
(
  Id int Primary Key Identity(1,1),
  [TimeStamp] datetime2(7) not null
)

insert into MyTable(TimeStamp) values('2020-03-29 19:40:46.8500000')
insert into MyTable(TimeStamp) values('2020-03-29 19:40:53.1000000')
insert into MyTable(TimeStamp) values('2020-03-18 17:15:48.2600000')

select * from MyTable
where
convert(datetimeoffset, convert(datetime2(7), timestamp, 1)) >= '3/18/2020 12:00:00 AM -04:00' and 
convert(datetimeoffset, convert(datetime2(7), timestamp, 1)) <= '3/29/2020 12:00:00 AM -04:00'
```

For example, in the above scenario, I should get ALL the records, but I'm getting only one record.

> 2020-03-18 17:15:48.2600000

Is the format of `DateTimeOffset` produced in `C#` affecting results or am I missing something?

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/232c33/10)

UPDATE:

Stored Procedure parameters:

```
,@StartDate     DateTimeOffset  = NULL
,@EndDate       DateTimeOffset  = NULL
```

In the example is used: start date `3/18/2019` and end date `3/29/2020`. The C# method that converts the dates to DateTimeOffset produced the following output:

```
d1 = 3/18/2020 12:00:00 AM -04:00
d2 = 3/29/2020 12:00:00 AM -04:00
```

Comment: What is `convert(datetime2(7), timestamp, 1)` trying to acheive here? `TimeStamp`is already a `datetime2` s converting it to one does nothing other than slow the query down.

Comment: @Larnu, I'm getting the same result without having to do any conversion. It was my latest attempt to see if I would to convert the date time to look like `2020-03-29 19:40:46.8500000 +00:00` maybe it would do the trick, but unfrotuntely, no.

Comment: If you want to filter a date range *inclusive* then you need to include the time as well in your upper range. The simplist way to do this is to add 1 to the date and change the filter to just `less than`. Example: User wants to filter between the dates 3/18 and 3/29. Make your where clause greater than or equal to 2020-3-18 and less than 2020-3-30. This comment does not take the time zone into account, it is strictly to illustrate that time is important in your where clause and you are currently not accounting for it.

Comment: Regarding timezones. If your dates are persisted as `datetime2` and the date info is UTC then you need to convert your input parameters to UTC and then filter by those parameters.

Comment: @Igor, essentially I'm trying to get the same output as if I would to do `convert(date, timestamp) >= '3/18/2020' and convert(date,timestamp)  <= '3/29/2020'` but taking in consideration the time zones. Would you please show an example as what you mean by adding 1?

Comment: `convert(date, timestamp)` ← There is no reason to do that. Just make sure your ado.net parameters are also of datetime2 and include the time aspect.

Comment: Doesn't `3/29/2020 12:00:00 AM` mean March 29th 00:00 hours ? The query runs fine in this case. How about changing the end date filter to less than or equal to `3/29/2020 23:59:59` ?

Comment: Why would you expect all 3 rows though? `2020-03-29T00:00:00-04:00` is `2020-03-29T04:00:00+00:00`. The times with an ID of 1 and 2 are ***after*** that. 15 hours and 40 minutes later.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why the question got a downvote?

Comment: Please include the values and types for `date1` and `date2` in your question.

Comment: Downvotes normally mean that the person though your question was either not helpful or didn't show any resarch. Considering my comment above, I suspect former. It's like asking "I have the numbers 1.1, 4.5 and 4.51. I asked for the nothings greater than or qual to 1, and less than or equal to 4, and only got 1 of the number. Why not all 3?" because 4.5 and 4.51 are *greater* than 4

Comment: @larnu, I'm on ETC time zone which is `-04:00` offset. So what I want to query is getting all data between 00:00 on 3/18 and including to 3/29. By including the offset the date and time still follows in that range. Am I missing something?

Comment: `2020-03-29 19:40:53.1000000+00:00` is ***after*** `2020-03-29T00:00:00-04:00` therefore `convert(datetimeoffset, convert(datetime2(7), timestamp, 1)) <= '3/29/2020 12:00:00 AM -04:00'` is false and the row is not displayed.

Comment: @smr5 if we're specific, your timezone is EDT, which is -04:00. EST is -05:00.

Comment: @Igor, the date and time in the where clause is the output of d1.ToString() / d2.ToString(). Are you looking for the actual value before .ToSTring()?

Comment: @smr5 - Please include the actual values and types for `date1` and `date2` as if you were creating an [mcve]. Only then can someone point you in the right direction and possibly provide a code snippet that would make sense in the context of your application.

Comment: @Larnu, I'm grabbing it from the following table: `select * from sys.time_zone_info` and `-04:00` is "US Eastern Standard Time". It's confusing :(

Comment: @Igor, one moment.

Comment: @Igor, updated the question to add the specifics you request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are making it more difficult than it needs to be.

*In your code*: Apply the `TimeZoneInfo` to the `DateTime` arguments supplied by the user. As the data is persisted as `DateTime2` use parameter types that match in this case `System.DateTime`. Based on your question you want the upper value to be inclusive, with Dates the easiest thing to do is to add 1 to the Date value (or 24 Hours is also acceptable) and change the query to be *less* than.

See the code below, you can modify this to be a stored proc. instead.

```
public void Test(DateTime argStartDate, DateTime argEndDate)
{
    var newOffSetDate = System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("");

    DateTime startParam = new DateTimeOffset(argStartDate, newOffSetDate.GetUtcOffset(argStartDate)).UtcDateTime;
    DateTime endParam = new DateTimeOffset(argEndDate, newOffSetDate.GetUtcOffset(argEndDate)).UtcDateTime;

    endParam = endParam.AddDays(1);

    const string query = "SELECT [column1], [column2], ... FROM [YourTable] WHERE [TimeStamp] >= @start AND [TimeStamp] < @end";
    using (var con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(""))
    using (var com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        com.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = startParam;
        com.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = endParam;
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Igor, you were right. I was over complicating it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query is returning row is because that's correct. You have 3 times, which you say are UTC:

```
2020-03-29 19:40:46.8500000+00:00
2020-03-29 19:40:53.1000000+00:00
2020-03-18 17:15:48.2600000+00:00
```

Let's therefore convert them to `-04:00` (which is EDT):

```
2020-03-29 15:40:46.8500000-04:00
2020-03-29 15:40:53.1000000-04:00
2020-03-18 13:15:48.2600000-04:00
```

You are then to see if the times are on or *after* `2020-03-18T00:00:00-04:00` and on or *before* `2020-03-29T00:00:00-04:00`.

`2020-03-18 13:15:48.2600000-04:00` is both after `2020-03-18T00:00:00-04:00` and before `2020-03-29T00:00:00-04:00`, so that is display. ON the other hand *both* `2020-03-29 15:40:53.1000000-04:00` and `2020-03-29 15:40:46.8500000-04:00` are **after** `2020-03-29T00:00:00-04:00` and so are not displayed.

You are getting 1 row, because only 1 of those rows fulfil there `WHERE`.

Comment: Oooo. I see now what you were referring earlier in your comment. So I guess what I'm looking for is end date should be `3/29/2020 23:59:00 PM -04:00`? I guess, maybe I didn't explain my requirement clearly. I'll update the question as well. What I need is if the users local date falls within date range, I want to include that without caring for the time. So for the range 3/18/2020 and 3/29/2020 I want all records that falls under that date, without having to worry about the time. In this case, I see my conversion is causing the issue.

Comment: If you want all the dates on 29 March regardless of time, then use `< 2020-03-30T00:00:00-04:00`, @smr5 .